# How to map/reduce an array of mixed types and sum them together

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

*This is a contrived example of what could be a very simple calculator, for learning purposes of Array.reduce/map.*

How can I sum `startValue` array with mixed operator types (only +/-)?

I have a stream of inputs that I want to map and then reduce to get the sum.

```
const sum = (p,c) => {
  return p + c;
};

let startValue = [1,2,3,'+',3,'+',4,'-',5,'+','-',5,3];
const finalValue = startValue
      .map(combineNumbersWithOperators) //or reduce
      .reduce(sum)
```

The first reducers would output:

```
startValue.map(combineNumbersWithOperators)
// [123,3,4,-5,-53]
```

The second reducer should work as intended:

```
[123,3,4,-5,-53].reduce(sum) 
// = 123
```

Comment: `.....'+','-',5,3]` ==> `3` ?????

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your first example isn't consistent with your intended signing conventions. The last `5,3` in your array should be parsed as 53 according to the way you combined `1,2,3` in the first part of your array. Also, I ignored the isolated `-` sign in your array as it's unclear/unexplained.

This solution is only using .reduce(); I don't think map or filter is necessary.

```
var flat = startValue.reduce(function(a,b) {
  if (b.toString() === '-') {
    var arr = a.toString().split('%');
    arr[arr.length - 1] = '-' + arr[arr.length-1];
    return arr.join('%') + '%';
  } else if (b.toString() === '+') {
    return a.toString() + '%';
  }
  return a.toString() + b.toString();
}).split('%').reduce(function(a,b){
  if (b === '-') {
    return a;
  }
  return a + parseInt(b);
  },0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in one go using `forEach` and a couple utility functions.

From the top of my head:

```
const array = [1,2,3,'+',3,'+',4,'-',5,'+','-',5,3];
let result = 0; /* the final result */
let numberAggregator = ''; /* used to aggregate the numbers */
let operator = '+'; /* last operator found, start by adding the first number */

const parseAggregator = function(aggregator) {
    let number = parseFloat(aggregator);
    if (isNaN(number)) {
        number = 0;
    }
    return number;
};

const performOperation = (left, right, operator) => {
    /* perform the lat operator's function */
    switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            return left + right;

        case '-':
            return left - right;

        default:
            /* you could add other operators here */
            return left; /* silently fail for unsupported operators :( */
    }
};

array.forEach(input => {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(input, 10)) && input !== '.') { /* it's an operator */
        /* parse the last aggregated number */
        const lastNumber = parseAggregator(numberAggregator);
        numberAggregator = '';

        /* perform the operation */
        result = performOperation(result, lastNumber, operator);

        /* save the new operator */
        operator = input;
    } else {
        /* add the input to the number aggregator */
        numberAggregator += input;
    }
});

/* once you get to the end, perform the last operation cached */
const lastNumber = parseFloat(numberAggregator);
result = performOperation(result, parseAggregator(numberAggregator), operator);

console.log(result); /* 123 + 3 + 4 - 5 - 53 = 72 */
```

Comment: OP asked for a contrived example for the learning purposes of Array.reduce/map.

Answer (score -1):

`map` will *map* each value of an array to some other value. Meaning the length of the array (i.e., the number of elements) will still be the same after running it through `map`. To achieve what you're asking you can use `filter` (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

So your example would become:

````
startValue.filter(combineNumbersWithOperators)
// [123,3,4,-5,-5,3]```
````